# Lift rogue query by mongolistfield

Tags: scala, lift

if I have field like:

```
object testDates extends MongoListField[Test, DateTime](this)
```

can I query some how if max date of this list is after now ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Test.where(_.testDates after now)
```

should do it